# Ardiuno Uno R3 to wifi network using ESP8266-01 not responding and Wifi shield not Present

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am using a sample example like esp wifi of Arduino IDE for connection of Arduino Uno R3 with WiFi using ESP8266-01.
On the first time compilation, I am getting a warning at compile time.
On the second time compilation, I am not getting any warnings.
On the Serial monitor, I am getting a message of a Wifi shield not present.

But if I execute a sample code as below and execute AT commands on Serial Monitor, I am able to execute a command and get a proper result.

```
void setup(){}void loop(){}
```

I have connected 3.3v of Arduino to ESP8266's VCC and GD_PD
RX of ESP to pin0 of Arduino
TX of ESP to pin1 of Arduino
Gnd is common

I have added all the libraries required to run modules.
Firmware version using AT+GMR is 0.40

Where I am making a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you try out using pins 2, 3 for TX & RX. Try switching the baud rates when you open serial monitor. The power source may be an issue as well but not most likely. Goodluck. It took me 2 days to figure out this module and I learned that I had to flash a firmware just using the Arduino r3 and my laptop lol Well it works now and is connected to my wifi.

Comment: Hi I have solved problem and I am able to send data to Mosquitto Broker.
I have used this link https://sonyarouje.com/2016/03/15/mqtt-communication-with-arduino-using-esp8266-esp-01/#comment-111773